# How to make prices update in configurable products front end

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am learning to use Magento to assemble configurable products. I have noticed that if I have different prices for each Simple Product, when I assemble the Configurable Product, the prices I used in the Simple products don't seem to update in the front end when I select them from the drop-down menu I created to cater for them. Only the same single price I used in the configurable price panel shows no matter which variant I select.

I have tried also placing the prices in the area allocated in 'Associated Products' panel but it shows in the front end as an addition (eg + $4.50) which is not desirable.

Is there a way to pass through the Simple Products price so it shows in the front end of the Configurable Product when I select each variant from the dropdown menu?

Do I need an extension to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As it happens I installed [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) and it appears to be working fine. I only enabled the 'Associated Products' option though which is all I needed and the prices from the simple products pass through and are updated on the product page as I select an attribute from the drop-down menu. The products then passes through to cart as a simple product as was mentioned by the creator of the extension.
My only advise would be to read the 'Reviews' on the page as there are many who have this working in latter versions of Magento but they needed to make some amends to the 'Configurable.php' as mentioned by 'tzvimoshe'in his comment dated 29 October in the reviews below the installer. There is also advice for that in the Q & A tab on the same page.
Also to make sure you log out then log back in once the extension is installed to ensure it loads properly in Magento's System Config (otherwise you get an error) and flush the Cache if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Copy

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml
```

To (If it isn't already there)

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml
```

And edit this line

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone') ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

Should work!

Comment: The didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I was thinking of using the Simple Configurable Products extension but it appears only to be supported up to v1.5 and some have made amends to the Configurable.php to make it work correctly up to version 1.8.1
Does anybody have a version working in 1.9.1?